# Schiff Base in Enzyme Mechanisms

Tags: biochemistry

Can a schiff base stabilize the transition state and form an intermediate as in covalent catalysis with a substrate in the same reaction? Basically I'm wondering if a schiff base creates a ping pong reaction.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to this one is a most definite 'yes'.  Almost all aminotransferases proceed via a [ping-pong mechanism](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Biological_Chemistry/Catalysts/Enzymatic_Kinetics/Ping-pong_mechanisms) where a schiff base involving [pyridoxal phosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyridoxal_phosphate) is an obligate intermediate, and where  the 'half-reation' modified enzyme form has often been isolated. An example is [aspartate aminotransferase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspartate_transaminase).

Let's also remind ourselves that a transition state is not an intermediate on the reaction pathway (in the TS bonds are in the process of being broken and formed), but may resemble one.